# How can I check for text on a site in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a simple program that logs in to a site using a WebBrowser, and it does it fine, but I want it to check if it actually logs in (correct details have been put in) and return the result to the program, I figured it would be possible to search for text on the page after submitting the login to see if it was successful or if it failed. How would I search for text on the page? My current code is this:

```
    Status.Text = "Validating details..."

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.site.com/login")
    wait(6000)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the All HtmlElementCollection of Document property to get the inner text or inner html of each html element in loaded document.
Here's a little test that I wrote :

```
public void Test()
    {
        var browser = new WebBrowser();
        var handle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, args) => { 
            foreach (HtmlElement element in browser.Document.All) 
                Console.WriteLine(element.InnerHtml);
            handle.Set();
            };
        browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        handle.WaitOne();

    }
```